# Draw polygon on google map and get the selected area

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing, android-geofence

i want to develop an android application, want to draw a polygon on the map and i want to check my current location is inside or out side the polygon.Like Geo-fencing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PolyUtil.containsLocation` ([code here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java)) method from the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).